# Python: strptime() is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to convert a string to a date. If I am reading the [doc's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) correctly, the following code should work:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.strptime('January 01, 2015', '%B %d, %Y')
```

Instead, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Comment: Solution: `import _strptime`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import `datetime` from `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.strptime('January 01, 2015', '%B %d, %Y')
```

Or use:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('January 01, 2015', '%B %d, %Y')
```